# How to animate 3 textviews one by one?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have 3 text views I need to make them animate in the order one by one.

When 1st textview ends the animation the second one should start and when the second ones end the third should start.

this is my animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-5"
    android:toXDelta="15"
    android:repeatCount="15"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="70" />
</set>
```

this is the code that i tried

```
final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.animation);
    animation.reset();
    tv1.clearAnimation();
    tv1.startAnimation(animation);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            tv1.clearAnimation();
            tv2.clearAnimation();
            tv2.startAnimation(animation);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            tv2.clearAnimation();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html

Comment: I think you need combination of `ObjectAnimator`  and `AnimationSet` .I will give you an example if you want it to do that way.

Comment: @sunil sunny yes please

Comment: `this is the code` and what is the problem with it?

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko where will i add the third one

Comment: you may want to create another animationlistener  for the 3rd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `AnimationSet` works as combination of animations, not as separate animation on separate views. So if You can use the `ObjectAnimator` for animating the multiple view as follows: And use the `AnimatorSet` to start the animations together it may work.

**Note** : I have not tried it and sure if this works. But you can give it a try anyway.

```
ArrayList<ObjectAnimator> arrayListObjectAnimators = new ArrayList<ObjectAnimator>(); //ArrayList of ObjectAnimators

ObjectAnimator anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv1, "translationX", 100f);
arrayListObjectAnimators.add(anim1);

ObjectAnimator anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv2, "translationX", 100f);
arrayListObjectAnimators.add(anim2);

ObjectAnimator anim3 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv3, "translationX", 100f);
arrayListObjectAnimators.add(anim3);
...

ObjectAnimator[] objectAnimators = arrayListObjectAnimators.toArray(new ObjectAnimator[arrayListObjectAnimators.size()]);
AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
animSet.playTogether(objectAnimators);
animSet.setDuration(1000);//1sec
animSet.start();
```

Comment: now it translate to one side how can i make it translate to the other side and make it appear back to its orgin position , and also how can i increase its speed? @sunil sunny

Comment: You have to set everything in objectAnimator. The above code was just an eg. You have set ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv2, "translationX", -5,15);
anim1.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE); like that.

Comment: In short you need to define objectanimator with  R.anim.animation values

Answer (score 1):

**here is the updated and tested code**

I think you should do something like this :

```
//these should be global variables

List<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
List<Animation> animations = new ArrayList<>();
int i = 0;
//end of global variables

    views.add(findViewById(R.id.tv1));
    views.add(findViewById(R.id.tv2));
    views.add(findViewById(R.id.tv3));

    animations.add(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation));
    animations.add(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation));
    animations.add(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation));


    final Animation.AnimationListener listener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            i++;
            if (i < views.size()) {
                views.get(i).startAnimation(animations.get(i));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    };

    animations.get(0).setAnimationListener(listener);
    animations.get(1).setAnimationListener(listener);
    animations.get(2).setAnimationListener(listener);



    views.get(0).startAnimation(animations.get(0));
```

Comment: it does not work.. the tv1 will animate then after that  all tv1,tv2,tv3 starts animating together

Comment: ok, I just update the code with new one it should work because I tested it, the thing is I was trying to avoid creating array of animation and reuse only one but it seems hard to do that

Comment: Just add this 
if(i>=0)
{
views.get(i).clearAnimation();
}
i++;
 if (i < views.size()) {
 views.get(i).startAnimation(animations.get(i));
 }